# The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) Object?

Tags: java, android, gridview, undefined

I want to use Gridview and implement the multiple choose in a fragment.
But it show the error like `The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) Object`.
I done't know how to solve it , can Some one teach me how to do ?

The code in my Fragment.java

```
private FileListAdapter mFileListAdapter ;
GridView fileListView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.browserList) ;
fileListView.setAdapter(mFileListAdapter) ;

        fileListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ViewTag viewTag = (ViewTag) view.getTag();
                mFileListAdapter.changeState(position);
            }
        }) ;
        return view ;
    }
```

And the code in FileListAdapter.java

```
public class FileListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public void changeState(int position) {

        if(isMultiSelect) {
            imageStatues.put(position, !imageStatues.get(position));
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

And the error `The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) Object` happen at `imageStatues.put(position, !imageStatues.get(position));`

Does someone can teach me how to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: !imageStatues.get(position) remove the !

Comment: `!` is only defined for `boolean` (and `Boolean` where it will be unboxed from). `imageStatues.get()` probably results in an Object expression .. show the *declaration* of `imageStatues`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want

```
imageStatues.get(position) != null
```

or something similar.

Alternatively, if `imageStatues.get(position)` is supposed to be a `Boolean`, you are probably using a raw map and need to specify a generic parameter type in the declaration of `imageStatues`. You could also simply try casting `imageStatues.get(position)` to a `Boolean`.

Comment: You assume a lot in this answer cause OP doesn't provide any example, perhaps he didn't see that he has `!` in the code..it's not wrong but is about guessing of what he want to achieve

Comment: @nachokk - I made several assumptions, but I think they're all reasonable. First, `imageStatues` is probably a `Map` of some kind (because of the use of `get()` and `put()`). Second, OP seems to be either trying to test for null values or treating the values as booleans. I couldn't figure out which, so I tried to address both in my answer. (It's probably the latter, but if OP is a recent immigrant from the land of JavaScript, C/C++, or some other language that treats null values as `false`, it might be the former.) If the `!` were spurious, the entire line of code would be an elaborate no-op.

Comment: We don't know cause it's not a good question , when he reveals the secret you'll have my upvote :D

Comment: @nachokk - Well, from OP's posted answer, it appears I was on the right track with the second alternative in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I reference some web that how to use the Gridview.

And I change the code from `private HashMap imageStatues = new HashMap();` to `private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> imageStatues = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();`

It is working.

Thanks for everybody's help !

Comment: If you are using Java 7 or later, you can eliminate the type parameters on the right side of the assignment: `private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> imageStatues = new HashMap<>();` You might also consider declaring it as `private Map<Integer, Boolean> imageStatues = new HashMap<>();` (a.k.a. [programming to the interface](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html)).